# Get the progress percentage in Ajax post request

Tags: javascript

I'm currently developing a web application that has a feature of automatic creation of bulk scorecards, and the time of creating is a bit long, 1000 datas is equivalent to 7 minutes of scorecard creation, I don't want the user to just stare at the loading bar I've created and wait for 7 minutes until it will succeed.

My problem is how can i get the progress percentage in ajax post request?

I already tried this one but no luck.

```js
xhr: function () {
        var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        xhr.onprogress = function (e) {
            // For downloads
            if (e.lengthComputable) {
                console.log(e.loaded / e.total);
            }
        };
        xhr.upload.onprogress = function (e) {
            // For uploads
            if (e.lengthComputable) {
                console.log(e.loaded / e.total);
            }
        };
        return xhr;
    }
```

Comment: Does it not console log anything ? Have you tried putting an `else` there and see if it goes to the else ?

Comment: i already tried logging it in console but it always display 1.

Comment: https://ibb.co/kVG74S 

thats the link of my screenshot in my console log

Comment: `function e()` shouldn't it be `function(e)` ?

Comment: sorry for the typo, i already changed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onprogress` and `upload.onprogress` events indicate the progress of **loading or uploading data**. I understand from the question that in your case it is the creation of data on the server side that is taking time. You will have to think of a custom way to calculate progress for that. For example if you know that it will always take about 7 minutes, you already know the progress.

I am able to print the progress with almost the same code as yours trying to load an image. Code at [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/junovaceyu/edit?html,output)

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/39811/pexels-photo-39811.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940', true);
xhr.send();
xhr.onprogress = function (e) {
    // For downloads
    if (e.lengthComputable) {
        console.log(e.loaded / e.total);
    }else{
      console.log("Unknown progress");
    }
};

xhr.upload.onprogress = function (e) {
    // For uploads
    if (e.lengthComputable) {
        console.log(e.loaded / e.total);
    }
};

xhr.onload = function(){
  console.log("loaded");
}

0.020057260632112467
0.12955284846249054
0.3485440241232467
0.49674801312022326
0.5894343173500785
0.7427281403126078
0.8960219632751371
```